# Bash script if condition does not work

Tags: bash, scripts, gnome-terminal

I've got a bash script with some user inputs. So in order to run smoothly it is nessecary to run in a terminal emulator (so the user can make the inputs).
Because of that i've wrote in the first lines of the script the following command:

```
#!/bin/bash

#if the script is running in background it gets visable
if ! x-terminal-emulator
    then
        path=$(pwd) #read current path
        me="$(basename "$(test -L "$0" && readlink "$0" || echo "$0")")" #read the name of the bash script
        x-terminal-emulator -- .$path/$me
        exit
fi

.
.
.
```

what it should do:
So when it runs in the terminal emulator it shoult ignore the statements and jump to the next step of the script but when it runs in the background, it should open a new terminal emulator and run the script there.

what it does:
But when I run it in a terminal emulator(1) it opens a new terminal emulator(2) where nothin happens and in the original terminal emulator (1) the script goes to the next steps.

Comment: `x-terminal-emulator` runs the emulator, it doesn't test whether it already runs in one.

Comment: Unless you specifically need to check for a terminal *emulator*, probably what you want is `test -t 0` or `[ -t 0 ]` to test whether stdin is a TTY

Comment: `if ! x-terminal-emulator` does exactly what it's intended to do: launch x-terminal-emulator and execute the `then` clause if it terminated with a non-zero exit status. But that is probably not what you intended to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way. Instead, just have the user launch your script in the terminal by typing a command. Alternatively, for easy and visible user access, have your script launched through a .desktop file. This will appear as an item in the application menu, or may be put on the desktop. If you include the line "Terminal=true", the executable (your script) will automatically be executed in a terminal emulator.